# Displaying nodeContent in orgchart (dabeng) when using ul datasource

Tags: javascript, orgchart

I am using [debang's orgchart.js](https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart.js/) file to display an organizational chart. I have the following `ul` structure that shows well on the page. It's just I do not know how to display the node contents. Following is what I have tried.

```
<ul id="ul-data">
  <li title="Project Manager">Reza Saberi
    <ul>
       <li title="Project Associate">Ali Karimi</li>
       <li title="Data Analyst">Ahmad Basir</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and the following is the js:

```
$('#chart').orgchart({
  'data' : $('#ul-data'),
  'pan': true,
  'nodeContent': 'title'
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed ul source will only display names, to display content please use ajax source or json source.